# Combine Vector advantages with Bitmap in an HTML canvas element - how?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, svg

What I am trying to do is create a game that has an extreme amount of zoom-ability on a canvas element. I would like to make use of the advantage that vector graphics have insofar as being able to be programmatically created at runtime, with the high performance of bitmap images.

What I would like to do is programmatically create the first-frame image of a game "sprite"... this would be a vector image. After the first frame though, I do not want to keep wasting CPU cycles on drawing the image though.. i would like to cache it as a bitmap/high performance image for that zoom level.

Following this, if the user zooms in by >20%, I then redraw the image with a higher level of detail vector image. As above, this vector image would then be cached and optimized.

[image: zoomed out]

As you can see here, this would be a pretty basic space ship.. I would first render it programmatically as a vector and then.. raster it I guess? Goal is to avoid wasting CPU.

If the user zooms in...

[image: zoomed in]

A new vector image of the same shape would be drawn, albeit with a much higher level of detail. This is basically a Level Of Detail system. In this case as well, after the initial programmatic draw, I would "raster" the image for maximum performance.

Does anyone have ideas on what tools I would need to make this a reality inside of a HTML canvas? (The rest of the game will be running inside of the canvas element..)

Thank you very much for your thoughts.

**Edit: I wanted to add... perhaps the route of rendering an image via SVG (programmatically), then pushing that png file into the canvas using drawimage(), might provide some success? Something similar? Hmm...

Comment: You don't need to convert to PNG.  Most browsers will accept an SVG in `drawImage`.

Comment: The idea is for the initial frame to be rendered as a SVG then converted into a PNG that we can reuse. SVG can indeed be used in the browser directly, but it incurs a much larger CPU cost if rendered every frame... I know that some browsers allow for "bitmap caching" of the SVG image, where after and SVG image is initially created, it will be cached as a bitmap until there is a change in size or alpha.. however i'm not sure how much control I have over this caching. Also, BMP images are huge compared to a compressed PNG. Would like to cache a PNG instead to be reused later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question.

The way to do this is to first create an SVG file, and then convert it to a PNG file on the client using "canvg". The PNG can be created at different levels of details based on what you want, and in this way you could create a dynamic LOD system.

Flash does something similar automatically by cashing a bitmap image of the SVG file... it's called "pre-rendering". If the SVG isn't scaled or the alpha isn't changed, flash will just use the bitmap instead (much faster then continuously re-rendering the SVG file, in complex cases). Size (and thus detail) of the PNG output can be modified however you like, and so pre-rendering could be done based on events as well.

From this information, I have decided to implement the LOD system such that SVG is used whilst the user is actively zooming (scaling the target "sprite"), and then as the zoom slows down, compute a PNG pre-render. Also, at extremely high levels of zoom, I simply use the SVG, as it is much easier for the CPU to compute SVG's at high resolution, then bitmap images that cover most of the screen. (just take a look at some of the HTML5 icon tests that put lots of icons on the screen... the bigger the icons are, the slower it runs).

Thanks very much to everyone's comments here and I hope that my question/answer has helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

Check out that article , but it seems there is no standard method to do what you want and it may fail in IE.

http://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/#svg_to_canvas

You should perhaps go with an all SVG game , or provide a maximum zooming rate to your game and  use big images as sprite assets. it would not have been a problem using flash,but i guess you wont go with flash anyway.

Maybe there is a framework that can translate SVG into a "canvas drawing sequence" but i would not bet on high performances in that case.